# How to highlight password field by default in SDDM (Lubuntu)?

Tags: lubuntu, login, lxqt, sddm

I have installed Lubuntu 21.04. The sddm login page had the password field selected by default but after the update that's not the case. I have to manually select password field before typing it. Is there a way to have the password field selected by default?

Comment: I think you'll find that even though the password field is not highlighted by default, it'll still work as you expect (assuming you've only got a single user setup on the box).  Try it.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thank you! Is this a bug?

Comment: If it is, it's very likely https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sddm/+bug/1885530   (Note: I tend to ignore it, and don't re-test for it often *if* at all.. I can see I listed only for *focal* (20.04), but also was reported in *groovy* in QA-testing.. but never *hirsute* (21.04).   If you believe that describes your issue, and you have a launchpad account, I'd recommend you clicking the "affects me too" & leaving a comment with some details.  That may give it some weight & may result in some attention.

Comment: If you believe it's a different issue, you can file your own bug report, see https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/bugs/  (or the generic Ubuntu link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).   I QA-tested the issue and could not see how it could be *maliciously* used by others, thus my lack of concern over it... also the "*affects only 1 person*" I consider proof it doesn't warrant attention...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll find that even though the password field is not highlighted by default (*on some setups*), it'll still work as you expect (*assuming you've only got a single user setup on the box; it works too for multiple users but I'd not advise using it there*). Try it.

*In comment later you asked if it is a bug.*

If it is, it's very likely https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sddm/+bug/1885530

(Note: *I tend to ignore it, and don't re-test for it often *if* at all.. I can see I listed only for *focal* (20.04), but also was reported in *groovy* in QA-testing*.. )

If you believe [that](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/sddm/+bug/1885530) describes your issue, and you have a launchpad account, I'd recommend you clicking the "*affects me too*" & leaving a comment with some details (ideally number of screens, video card & layout of monitors, ie. 2xlandscape, landscape+portrait, 2xportrait etc).  That may give it some weight & may result in some attention.

If you believe it's a different issue, you can file your own bug report, see https://phab.lubuntu.me/w/bugs/  (or the generic [Ubuntu bug reporting link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs)).

**Please note, I QA-tested the issue and could not see how it could be *maliciously* used by others** (in both *focal* & *groovy*), thus my lack of concern over it... also the "*affects only 1 person*" I consider proof it doesn't warrant much attention (*including why I haven't re-tested for it on either hirsute & impish though I'm convinced it still occurs on those too*!).

Comment: Note: My QA-testing was maybe 5-8 minutes on each of two boxes trying to login using invalid passwords and was **far** from exhaustive..  It was primarily enough to satisfy myself the issue was of little concern (and my describing it as *password doesn't leave dots on the being entered* or the bug title as I'd concluded it worked perfectly; the issue was on certain display setups the password box wasn't treated as if active visually thus *dots* didn't appear on entry of password but it acted as expected otherwise)

Comment: QA = Quality Assurance..

Comment: Thank you. I have dual monitor setup if that makes any difference.

Comment: Thanks, it's best if that detail is added to the bug report (it's where the Lubuntu team will look for details/clues).  I personally think it's related to video card; as this askubu question prompted me to do some testing with *impish* you'll note with comment #4, those systems use dual screens, in fact two boxes share the same monitors yet only one was impacted -- meaning it's hardware differences I believe  (*given identical software & testing was done on both*..)

Answer (score 0):

An solution is search in `main.qml` or `login.qml`, in which part are located the form or the input for the password.
In this file, put the property `focus:primaryScreen`, this allows you to enter your password and login. But, you wont see the password field changing (this because in dual monitor the screen, by default, is not the primary).
In my case,im using Lubuntu default theme and just replace `focus:true` to `focus:primaryScreen` at the line 130 in `Main.qml` located in `/usr/share/sddm/themes/lubuntu/`

Comment: Please [edit] your answer into a few sentences, rather than one really long one.

Comment: I agree with @Greenonline re: formatting.  I personally would prefer a release provided (the line 130 may apply for your release, but files change over time so reference to a release may warn users to look in nearby lines if line 130 isn't exactly what you said.

Comment: `this make than you can put your password, press enter and login` - does this mean  `this allows you to enter your password and login` or does it mean `you have to authenticate to make the change`? I am guessing the former...

Comment: the first thing, than allow to enter your password and login